# Trouble sending data from TextField from within xib UIView popup back to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, uitextfield

I'm having trouble getting data from user inputs within a popup UIView. I'm confused because the TextFieldDelegate function prints nil when attempting print(delegate) but succeeds with print(name), and the save button prints "" when attempting print(name) but succeeds with print(delegate).

I need to get the name variable back to the ViewController.

ViewController file:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

     var popUp: PopUp?

     override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
     }
}

extension ViewController: PopUpDelegate {

     func saveName(_ name: String) {
          print(name) // attempting print for testing
     }

     @IBAction func popUpButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
          self.popUp = PopUp(frame: self.view.frame, sender: self)
          self.view.addSubview(popUp!)
     }
}
```

PopUp file:

```
class PopUp: UIView {

     @IBOutlet weak var textOutlet: UITextField!
     var delegate: PopUpDelegate?
     var name = ""
     
     override func awakeFromNib() {
          super.awakeFromNib()
          textOutlet.delegate = self
     }

     required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
          super.init(coder: coder)
     }

     init(frame: CGRect, sender: PopUpDelegate) {
          super.init(frame: frame)
          xibSetup(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
          self.delegate = sender
     }

     func xibSetup(frame: CGRect) {
          let view = loadXib()
          view.frame = frame
          addSubview(view)
     } 
    
     func loadXib() -> UIView {
          let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
          let nib = UINib(nibName: "PopUp", bundle: bundle)
          let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
          return view!
     }

     @IBAction func cancelButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
          self.removeFromSuperview()
     }

     @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: UIButton) 
          print(delegate) // prints ViewController
          print(name) // prints ""
          delegate?.saveName(name) // prints ""
          self.removeFromSuperview()
     }
}

extension PopUp: UITextFieldDelegate {

     func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
          if textField.text != "" {
               textField.endEditing(true)
               return true
          } else {
               textField.placeholder = "name required*"
          }
          return true
     }
    
     func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
          if textField.text != "" {
               name = textField.text! 
               print(delegate) // prints nil
               print(name) // prints inputted text
               delegate?.saveName(name) // no action
          } else {
               textField.placeholder = "name required*"
          }
     }
}

protocol PopUpDelegate {
    func saveName(_ name: String)
}
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that the text fields delegate is another instance of `PopUp` that has been created from the NIB.  Try setting the text field's delegate explicitly to `self` in your code.

Comment: Yup I guess the awakeFromNib() was creating its own instance. I moved the delegate setting to the init() and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, all you need to just pass PopUp's delegate to you ViewController.

Update your viewDidLoad() in ViewController as:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.popUp?.delegate = self
 }
```